# Add the same git hunk in many files

Tags: git, diff

I have a few hundred xml files in a git repository, and I've added the lines

```
<foo>
    <baz>bar</baz>
</foo>
```

to 50 of them. Some other changes have been made, but I only want to stage the changes which are this exact addition. Is there a way to do this in only a few steps? At the moment I think I'd have to run the entire repo through `git add --patch` and hit yes fifty times, which would take ages.

Comment: Should have make another branch, but the problem is interesting.
I haven't a solution now but, I'd like to know if there is any.
I was thinking about a feature like filter-branch (which allow to script rebasing and thus rewrite branch history with one command line) but for the add command.

Comment: If you can make the change with e.g. `sed`, something like `set -- $(git ls-files -s path/to/file); update-index --cacheinfo $1 $(git show path/to/file | sed 'make-the-change' | git hash-object -w) path/to/file)` should do it.